# How to get data from mysql and group them in weeks, also separating by month

Tags: mysql

I have mysql database and is full of over 2 years of data.  How can I make a query in a way that it will get the result as below?:

```
January
   Week 1
      ...
      data rows here
      ....
   Week 2
      ...
      ...
   Week 3
      ...
      ...
   Week 4
      ...
      ...

February (same as above)
```

These are the field structures:

```
- date (in yyyy-mm-dd format)
- job (integer autoincrement)
- person (varchar)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, it will generate output pretty similar to one required by you

```
SELECT MONTH(date) AS MONTH, WEEK(date) AS WEEK, DATE_FORMAT(date, %Y-%m-%d) AS DATE, job AS JOB, person AS PERSON GROUP BY WEEK(date);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 GROUP BY year(record_date), MONTH(record_date)
```

Check out the [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

It has to be a query, or you can use ajax too? Using ajax you could do a loop in javascript:

```
date = [initial date]
while date <= [final date] {
    divUpdate = 'divrecs'; // will be used in updateDiv function
    url = 'getrecs.php?date1='+date+'&date2='+(date+6);
    conecta(url,updateDiv);
    date = date+7;
}
```

And inside getrecs your query would be:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("select * from yourtable where date >= '".$_GET['date1']."' and date <= '".$_GET['date2']."'");
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
        echo "Do anything with your data here: $row[1] etc<BR>";
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT 
    MONTH(created_datetime) AS month, 
    WEEK(created_datetime) AS week, 
    DATE(created_datetime) AS date,
    COUNT(id) AS count
 FROM  users 
 WHERE date(created_datetime) BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-12-31'
 GROUP BY month
 ORDER BY created_datetime`

**If you want records date wise that you need to use GROUP BY date.

If you want records weekly that you need to use GROUP BY week.

If you want records monthly that you need to use GROUP BY month.**