# Mysql: show data by week

Tags: mysql

i used this query

```
   SELECT DATE( created_date ) AS date, FLOOR( time_to_sec( timediff( MAX( created_date ) , MIN( created_date ) ) ) /3600 ) AS Hours
    FROM bir_jobs_tracker
    GROUP BY date
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

and result is

```
 date   Hours
2015-08-25  0
2015-08-26  5
2015-08-27  0
2015-08-28  5
2015-09-01  2
2015-09-02  4
2015-09-15  0
2015-09-17  0
```

it returns hours calculate on daily bases, how can edit my query so that i can show them on weekly bases and add hours of 7 days in each week

require output

```
 date   Hours
2015-08-22  10
2015-09-01  6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get data from mysql and group them in weeks, also separating by month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430600/how-to-get-data-from-mysql-and-group-them-in-weeks-also-separating-by-month)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using week(), it will return week number of the date, so you can easily group weeks together. Just be careful to include a year in your grouping too, or you can end up merging weeks of different years.

```
SELECT WEEK(DATE( created_date ) AS date ...
```

Edit: 
since you need to calculate it on per day basis first, start running your query first, and then on its result:

```
SELECT WEEK(date) as week, YEAR(date) as year, SUM(hours) as hours_weekly
FROM (your_result)
GROUP BY year, week
```

I don't have mysql around to check syntax, but you should get the idea.

Comment: it takes min and max time of week, i do not want this, i want first it calculate hours of days, and then show them my week and add hours of each day in week

Comment: ok, I didnt get into your calculating method before, check the edit